PnP.Core - Mock of IFolderCollection failing
I need to mock a sharepoint document library returning a list of 6 files.  This is the logic I am using to create a mock system.
public class SharePointDocLibraryUtilsTestFactory
{
    private Mock<IPnPCoreSDKClient> _mockPnPCoreSDKClient;
    private Mock<IPnPContext> _mockPnpContext;
    private ITestOutputHelper _output;

    public SharePointDocLibraryUtilsTestFactory(ITestOutputHelper output)
    {
        _mockPnPCoreSDKClient = new Mock<IPnPCoreSDKClient>();
        _mockPnpContext = new Mock<IPnPContext>();
        _mockPnPCoreSDKClient.Setup(client => client.GetPnPContextAsync(It.IsAny<string>())).ReturnsAsync(_mockPnpContext.Object);
        _output = output;
    }

    public IList SetupMockSharePointLibrary()
    {
        var mockList = new Mock<IList>();
        var mockRootFolder = new Mock<IFolder>();
        var mockWeb = new Mock<IWeb>();
        var subfolders = new List<IFolder>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            var mockFolder = new Mock<IFolder>();
            var mockFileCollection = new Mock<IFileCollection>();
            var mockFiles = new List<IFile>();

            for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
            {
                var mockFile = new Mock<IFile>();
                mockFile.Setup(f => f.Name).Returns($"File_{i}_{j}.txt");
                mockFile.Setup(f => f.ServerRelativeUrl).Returns($"/sites/me/Documents/folder_{i}/File_{i}_{j}.txt");
                mockFiles.Add(mockFile.Object);
            }

            mockFileCollection.Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator()).Returns(() => mockFiles.GetEnumerator());
            mockFolder.Setup(f => f.Files).Returns(mockFileCollection.Object);
            subfolders.Add(mockFolder.Object);
        }

        // Setup folder collection to return our mock folders  
        var mockFolderCollection = new Mock<IFolderCollection>();
        mockFolderCollection.Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator()).Returns(() => subfolders.GetEnumerator());
        mockRootFolder.Setup(f => f.Folders).Returns(mockFolderCollection.Object);


        // Setup the mock list to return the root folder and the correct item count  
        mockList.Setup(l => l.RootFolder).Returns(mockRootFolder.Object);

        // Setup the mock web to return the mock list  
        mockWeb.Setup(web => web.Lists.GetByTitleAsync(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<Expression<Func<IList, object>>>()))
               .ReturnsAsync(mockList.Object);


        //mockList.Setup(l => l.RootFolder).Returns(mockRootFolder.Object);
        //mockWeb.Setup(web => web.Lists.GetByTitleAsync(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<Expression<Func<IList, object>>>()))
        //      .ReturnsAsync(mockList.Object);


        _output.WriteLine($"Total file list count {mockList.Object.ItemCount}");
        return mockList.Object;
    }
}

When i debug this code, I can see that the mockFolderCollection is empty.  This is the output from my immediate window:
mockFolderCollection
{Mock<IFolderCollection:1>}
    Behavior: Default
    CallBase: false
    DefaultValue: Empty
    DefaultValueProvider: {Moq.EmptyDefaultValueProvider}
    Invocations: {Moq.InvocationCollection}
    Name: "Mock<IFolderCollection:1>"
    Object (Moq.Mock): {Mock<IFolderCollection:1>.Object}
    Object: {Mock<IFolderCollection:1>.Object}
    Setups: {Moq.SetupCollection}
    Switches: Default

Because this is empty, when it calls the SUT, i get a null error by the time it hits this specific function:
    private async Task ProcessFolderAsync(IFolder folder, SharePointDocLibraryInventory result, bool recursive, string checksumType)
    {
        // Process files in the current folder
        foreach (var file in folder.Files)
        {
            string checksum = await GenerateChecksumAsync(file, checksumType);
            result.Files.Add(new SynchronizedSharePointDocument
            {
                Name = file.Name,
                FullPath = file.ServerRelativeUrl,
                RelativePath = file.ServerRelativeUrl.Replace(folder.ServerRelativeUrl, "").TrimStart('/'),
                Checksum = checksum
            });
            result.TotalFiles++;
        }

        // Optionally process subfolders recursively
        if (recursive)
        {
            await folder.LoadAsync(f => f.Folders);
            foreach (var subfolder in folder.Folders)
            {
                result.TotalSubdirectories++;
                await ProcessFolderAsync(subfolder, result, recursive, checksumType);
            }
        }
    }

The folder parameter comes in as null.

The collection isn't empty, which this passing test demonstrates:
[Fact]
public void AttemptRepro()
{
    var factory = new SharePointDocLibraryUtilsTestFactory(output);
    var actual = factory.SetupMockSharePointLibrary();
    Assert.Equal(3, actual.RootFolder.Folders.Count());
}

The Empty value you're seeing in the immediate window is just the default Moq DefaultValue. This is an enum, and the documentation of Empty says:

Default behavior, which generates empty values for value types (i.e. default(int)), empty array and enumerables, and nulls for all other reference types.

All that said, collections are typically deterministic, which means that they're already testable. Instead of creating Test Doubles with dynamic mocks, do yourself a favour and use real collection classes. That's going to be much easier.

but the test fails with an error saying the folder parameter passed in to ProcessFolderAsync  is empty.

@dot Which test? Please update the OP so that we have a chance of reproducing the problem.
